# How I do add new image on my background images

Tags: android

How do I add new images on my previous background image?
i.e I have selected one image from gallery after that I choose another image from gallery and  put it on the previous image.

Comment: explain in details about your problems and code?

Comment: i want create like collage application i have one background and select multiple images from gallery and arrange it i add background and now i add another image gallery how it be done

Comment: Do you mean perfect grid collage or just random pictures one on another?
did you get your solution?